# (flash 8, as2) cannot connect in my mulltiplayer flash game that is using smartfoxserver pro

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, smartfoxserver

i am experimenting on making a multiplayer game using smartfoxserver pro, but i have a problem,

when i click on the "connect" button (you need to put in "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" on the ip box), it cannot connect and gives me the following error:

**localhost**

**** Socket connection failed. Trying BlueBox ****

**[  Send  ]: connect**

**Error opening URL "http://localhost:8080/BlueBox/HttpBox.do"**

how can i fix this error? heres the code just incase

```
import it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.*

/*#include "lib/[flashAPI].as"
#include "lib/easingEquations.as"
#include "lib/easing.as"*/

/*
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*   [ Avatar Chat ] version 1.1.0 -- Actionscript 2.0
*   a SmartFoxServer sample application
*
*   www.smartfoxserver.com
*   (c) 2004 gotoAndPlay()
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
stop()
Stage.showMenu = false


//----------------------------------------------------------
// Setup global variables
//----------------------------------------------------------
var stageW:Number = 780
var stageH:Number = 490

// hide semi-transparent panel
// used when a dialog box is shown

// isBusy is true when the application
// is requiring input through a dialog box
// When true all other controls are temporarily disabled
_global.isBusy = false

// An event queue
var evtQueue:Array = []


//----------------------------------------------------------
// Setup global variables
//----------------------------------------------------------
showLogin(false)
var smartfox:SmartFoxClient = new SmartFoxClient()



//----------------------------------------------------------
// Server configuration
//
// ip   = IP address of the server, if the server is running
//        locally use 127.0.0.1
// port = default value is 9339
// zone = the Server "zone" name for this application
//----------------------------------------------------------

var port:Number     = 9339
var zone:String     = "simpleChat"


_root.butt_check.onRelease = function() {
    var ip:String       = _root.ip_txt.text;
    trace(_root.ip_txt.text);
    status_txt.text = "Connecting..."
smartfox.onConnection = handleConnection
smartfox.debug = true

// Connect to the server
smartfox.connect(ip, port);
}



//----------------------------------------------------------
// Handle connection response from server
//----------------------------------------------------------
function handleConnection(success:Boolean)
{
    if (success)
    {
        status_txt.text = "Connected, please login:"
        showLogin(true)
        butt_login.onRelease = sendLogin
    }
    else
    {
        status_txt.text = "Can't connect!"
    }
}



//----------------------------------------------------------
// Send login params to the server
// server.login(zone, nickName, password)
//----------------------------------------------------------
function sendLogin()
{
    if (!_global.isBusy)
        smartfox.login(zone, login_txt.text, null)
}



//----------------------------------------------------------
// Handle login response from server
//----------------------------------------------------------
smartfox.onLogin = function(resObj:Object)
{
    if (resObj.success)
    {
        // Login Succesfull
        _global.myName = resObj.name
    }
    else
    {
        // Login Failed
        _gloabl.isBusy  = true
        
        // Show an error window
        var win:MovieClip = showWindow("errorWindow")
        win.errorMsg.text = resObj.error
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------
// Handle the onRoomListUpdate here and keep it in the
// queue. We'll handle it in the next frame.
//----------------------------------------------------------
smartfox.onRoomListUpdate = function(o:Object)
{
    evtQueue.push(o)
    gotoAndStop("chat")
}


//----------------------------------------------------------
// Handle unexpected server disconnection
//----------------------------------------------------------
smartfox.onConnectionLost = function()
{
    gotoAndStop("connect")
}



//----------------------------------------------------------
// Show / Hides the login input field and submit button
//----------------------------------------------------------
function showLogin(bool:Boolean)
{
    //butt_login._visible = bool
    //login_txt._visible = bool
    //loginBox._visible = bool
    
    if (bool)
        Selection.setFocus("login_txt")
}



//----------------------------------------------------------
// Shows a popup window and disables all other controls
//----------------------------------------------------------
function showWindow(linkageName:String):MovieClip
{
    _global.isBusy = true
    
    disabler._visible = true
    
    roomList_lb.setEnabled(false)
    userList_lb.setEnabled(false)
    
    var win = _root.attachMovie(linkageName, linkageName, 9999)
        
    win._x = (stageW / 2) - (win._width / 2)
    win._y = (stageH / 2) - (win._height / 2)
    
    return win
}



//----------------------------------------------------------
// Hides a popup window and re-enable the controls
//----------------------------------------------------------
function hideWindow(wName:String)
{
    this[wName].removeMovieClip()
    
    roomList_lb.setEnabled(true)
    userList_lb.setEnabled(true)
    
    disabler._visible = false
    _global.isBusy = false
}
```

i dont know how i can fix it

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is, but if you are failing to connect, I would double check your server is running, and the path and port are correct.
But I am really curious if AS2 and SmartFox are essential for you? There are much more modern and easy to use things out there. I don't think SmartFox even exists anymore. And I have not used AS2 and Flash 8 for decades. Don't get me wrong, I loved all of that back in the day. It started my career, but are you really using that?

Comment: i still use as2, flash 8, and smartfoxserver pro because its more simpler for me to use and make games and animations

Comment: Awesome! Good for you! Do you post your games or animations somewhere?

Comment: Well, first of all, you should check if that URL is available in the most simple way — in the browser. If not, then it is not a Flash-side problem.

Comment: when i open the link to the ip (http://localhost:8080/BlueBox/HttpBox.do), it says that it isnt possible to access it

Comment: Well, there you have your answer. If the link does not open at all, then the problem is not the Flash-side problem, right?

Comment: i fixed the issue some days ago now, i just had to reinstall smartfoxserver pro but put it in "Desktop"